# Setting up a series of base/derived classes to process weather data

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I am designing a program which takes data from a bunch of weather stations around the world and runs some time series data on it.
I am looking for some guidance on how to correctly set up the class structures. My knowledge of design principles is pretty basic, so apologies in advance
if I have laid it out in a stupid manner

Program:

- Collect data from a bunch of weather stations around the world and
  then do time series analysis on it
- Data from different weather    stations comes in differing formats,
  denoted    `data_format_1,data_format_2`

There are 2 steps of tranforming this raw data:

- First into a structure called `weather_data_for_processing` - which
  contains data actually needed to crunch numbers, plus some technical
  data, like what format to save it in
- Then to a structure called `weather_data_for_crunching`, which contains only the data needed to crunch the numbers

It is pretty much a subset of the previous structure, but I was thinking to have a separate class for it, because in real life these classes are huge and it gets messy with having unnecessary data passed down

I have done the following:

- Created a base class `weather_station_core`, which has
  data which is common to all weather stations
- Created 2 derived classes, `data_format_1, data_format_2`
  which inherit from core, and describe the 2 formats in which data
  comes in CSV files from weather stations
- Function which wraps everything - called `process_weather_data_master`
- loads data from drive, then transforms it, then feeds into number cruncher
- Inside this wrapper function, there is another function which acts as
  yet another wrapper - `analyse_weather_and_save`
- Inside the wrapper there is the actual number cruncher func -
  crunch_numbers

Each of these functions wrapped in one another has a slightly different set of inputs and I am struggling to create a robust set of classes to:

- Avoid duplication of parameters as much as possible
- Keep it clean / not messy

If you could guide me in the right direction / or where to read in general, would be amazing, even if just generic guidance

Thank you for any help / pointers at all in advance

```
typedef std::pair<time_t, double> time_series_atom;

/// Every weather station has this data
struct weather_station_core{
int weather_station_id;
double latitude;
double longitude;
std::vector <time_series_atom> weather_data; 
};

/// Data Format 1
struct data_format_1 : weather_station_core {
int number_of_thermometers_at_station;
std::string thermometer_brand;
std::string file_format_to_save_processed_data_in;
};

/// Data Format 2
struct data_format_2 : weather_station_core {
int number_of_thermometers_at_station;
int year_started_operation;
};

/// data which is needed to perform the calculation PLUS some technical parameters, like how to save it on the drive
struct weather_data_for_processing : weather_station_core{  
std::vector <time_series_atom> weather_data_in_celcius; 
int number_of_thermometers_at_station;
std::string file_format_to_save_processed_data_in;
};

/// this structure is just the data which is needed to perform the calculation
struct weather_data_for_crunching : weather_station_core{  
std::vector <time_series_atom> weather_data_in_celcius; 
};

/// RESULTS
struct analysed_weather_data : weather_station_core{  
    std::vector<double> measurement_error;
};



namespace weather{

/// Load data on weather stations from a CSV file - in 2 different formats
data_format_1 load_raw_input_format_1(std::string full_file_path_to_input_file); /// loads data from a CSV file into an object of data_format_1
data_format_2 load_raw_input_format_2(std::string full_file_path_to_input_file); /// loads data from a CSV file into an object of data_format_1

/// Process the data_format_1, data_format_2 input structures into something common that feeds into the next function
weather_data_for_processing process_format_1(data_format_1);
weather_data_for_processing process_format_2(data_format_2);

processed_weather_data_core reduce_data(weather_data_for_processing);

/// Process and crunch numbers
void process_weather_data_master(int format_id); /// outermost function containing analyse and save, and inside it, crunch
void analyse_weather_and_save(weather_data_for_processing); /// 2nd most outermost
analysed_weather_data crunch_numbers(weather_data_for_crunching); /// function wrapper inside the 2 functions above



/// Utility
void save_weather_data(analysed_weather_data, std::string full_file_path); // saves the processed data to drive
}


void weather::process_weather_data_master(int format_id){

std::string full_file_path_to_input_file = "C:/users/weather_data.csv";

data_format_1 D1; data_format_2 D2;

weather_data_for_processing DD:

if (format_id == 1) {D1 =  load_raw_input_format_1(std::string full_file_path_to_input_file);
analyse_weather_and_save(process_format_1(D1));
}

if (format_id == 2) {D2 =  load_raw_input_format_2(std::string full_file_path_to_input_file);
analyse_weather_and_save(process_format_2(D2));
}


}


void weather::analyse_weather_and_save(weather_data_for_processing D){
std::string drive_location = "C:/users/weather_data";
std::string file_format = D.file_format_to_save_processed_data_in;
std::string full_file_path = drive_location + "processed_weather_data" + file_format;

processed_weather_data_core F = reduce_data(D);

analysed_weather_data OUTPUT = crunch_numbers(F);
save_weather_data(OUTPUT,full_file_path);

}
```

Comment: _"...If you could guide me in the right direction / or where to read in general, would be amazing, even if just generic guidance.."_: Too broad. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't think this question should really involve C++. It's more OOP. You may have better luck at the software engineering stack exchange.

Comment: is `weather_data_in_celcius` the same data as `weather_data`? Or the same data in different units? It looks like `weather_data_for_processing` contains two copies of the data. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Chris Drew the idea is that [code]weather_data[/code] can be in either celcius or fahrenheit - an in celcius is the processed version of the raw input which can be in either units

Answer (score 2):

Much of this question is too broad for Stackoverflow. This is not the place for code reviews but I think you have a valid question about how to avoid code duplication in the particular area where you are dealing with multiple file formats.

I would start by encapsulating the processing of each file format into a class rather than having separate functions:

```
struct DataFormat1Loader {
  data_format_1 load_raw_input_format(std::string full_file_path_to_input_file);
  weather_data_for_processing process_raw_data(data_format_1);
};

struct DataFormat2Loader {
  data_format_2 load_raw_input_format(std::string full_file_path_to_input_file);
  weather_data_for_processing process_raw_data(data_format_2);
};
```

This then opens up some options, you could get these loaders to inherit from an abstract base class and treat them polymorphically. Or it is probably easier to use them in a function template:

```
template<typename FormatLoader>
void process_weather_data(FormatLoader loader) {
  std::string full_file_path_to_input_file = "C:/users/weather_data.csv";

  auto raw_data = loader.load_raw_input_format(full_file_path_to_input_file);
  auto data_for_processing = loader.process_raw_data(raw_data);
  analyse_weather_and_save(data_for_processing);
}
```

The calling code then just has to create the correct file format loader:

```
void weather::process_weather_data_master(int format_id) {
  if (format_id == 1) {
    process_weather_data(DataFormat1Loader{});
  }
  if (format_id == 2) {
    process_weather_data(DataFormat2Loader{});
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, very helpful. what would you recommend as a good place to ask this kind of questions, if not here?